# Parse nested json in unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have an issue parsing this json :

```
{
    "product_info":
    {
        "title": "Product Name"
    }
}
```

here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ReadJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text myText;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class ProductInfo
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class RootObject
    {
        public ProductInfo product_info { get; set; }
    }

    void Start () {

        TextAsset asset = Resources.Load (Path.Combine ("Json", "toulouse")) as TextAsset;

        RootObject m = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject> (asset.text);

        Debug.Log (m.product_info.title);

    }
}
```

I receive this error message : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I already tried, with success to parse a not nested json but not I don't understand why but doesn't work even after created the appropriated class.

Comment: If you define RootObject as a dynamic object, could this help you find out the necessary structure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JsonUtility does not support properties. Just remove the { get; set;}

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ProductInfo
{
    public string title;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public ProductInfo product_info;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One day looking for this solution! Works great thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Unity's JSON implementation is much like what a small child would write for their CS1 project.  It's "lacking" at best for any serious JSON usage... ;-)

Recommend using: [*JSON .NET For Unity*](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) if you can pony up for it.

Or... use https://github.com/Bekwnn/UnityJsonHelper if you wish to stick with Unity's JSON implementation.  This library solves the exact problem you describe.

Comment: this is also pretty great and free: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject